# How do skip the revision check when putting a document into couchdb using curl?

Tags: couchdb

I am putting a document into couchdb like this:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:5984/bucket/keyname_1 \
    -d '{"foo":"bar"}'
```

This works just fine as long as the document doesn't already exist.  If it does exist, I need to include a "_rev" key to validate that I am updating an existing document:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:5984/bucket/keyname_1 \
    -d '{"_rev":"2-207df9da","foo":"bar"}'
```

If the _rev key is missing, or if the _rev key is doesn't match what's in the existing record, this throws a "conflict" error.  This is how you know that a revision isn't being thrown away.

But what if I want to write it unconditionally, and bypass this check?

I have a design where I am updating the main record, with the check, and then I want to save a brief summary record with only a couple fields that can be easily grabbed and downloaded for a summary screen.  Since I *just* updated the main record, I know that I have the latest copy.  I just want to do a write, and I don't want to have to do a read first just to get the _rev.  This would be redundant.

Is there any way that I can modify my request to tell couchbase to skip the _rev check and just put the document in unconditionally?

Comment: You mentionned Couchbase at the end of your question, I think it is a mistake, as you know Couchbase and CouchDB are two different projects/products : http://www.couchbase.com/couchbase-vs-couchdb

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983930/bulk-updating-a-couchdb-database-without-a-rev-value-per-document

Answer (score 3):

So you have two documents that you want to update: main and summary. Even if you have the latest version of main, will that actually mean you have the latest version of summary as well or do you just want force the last no matter what? If, then you might have a look at Update handlers: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers

Also, if you go with some kind of secondary `GET` to fetch the latest `_rev`, use a cheaper `HEAD` request.

**EDIT**: BTW, why having two separate documents? Is the `Summary` one in fully complete with the `Main` one? All all the members found there? Could you then perhaps use Show or list functions? http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Formatting_with_Show_and_List

Comment: The summary one is a very small subset of what's in main.  When you have the latest version of main, it's guaranteed that you have the latest version of summary as well.  The summary only contains a handful of the fields found in the full record.  (BTW: we have the summary because these couple fields will be pulled MUCH more frequently than the data is updated, and we want to save bandwidth to the database by not downloading the whole record for only a couple of fields)

Comment: So did you take a look at "update handlers"? The documentation on that page even states "..updating individual fields in a document without first getting the latest revision, etc."

Comment: Also, even if they are in the same document, creating a view which returns the summary would eat disk space, but save the bandwith etc. Will be interesting to see what solution you go for.

Cheers,

//Dan

Answer (score 0):

Instead of PUTting the record, why not POST a new one?

That way, you keep a full record of all such log events, but you don't have to deal with document conflicts.

Comment: Because I don't need to keep a full record - it's not a log event.  I only want a summary record for a summary screen that will be used elsewhere and loaded frequently.